# jQuery submit() function not causing <form> to submit

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this...

```
<form action="/tags/3" class="edit_tag" id="edit_tag_3" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
  </div> 
  <input class="tag_form_field" id="tag_name" maxlength="255" name="tag[name]" size="42" type="text" value="" /> 
</form>
```

And I'm trying to submit it like this...

```
$('.tag_form_field').change(function() {
  $(event.target).closest('form').submit();
});
```

When I change the input, the form does not submit. Nothing happens -- no error.

I know the selector and the onChange() handler are both working. I tested them by replacing `submit()` with the jQuery `css()` function and it worked fine.

I tested it in Safari and Chrome on OS X with the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

I tried these as well with the same result...

```
$('.tag_form_field').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});

$('.tag_form_field').change(function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('form').submit();
});

$('.tag_form_field').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});

$('.tag_form_field').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(this).closest('form.edit_tag')[0].submit();`

Otherwise it just triggers the `submit` event on the form.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to trigger the submit event on the form. That's the goal. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder. Can you try phrasing it this way:

```
$('.tag_form_field').change(function(e){
    $(e.target).closest('form.edit_tag').submit();
});
```

jQuery should take care of properly encapsulating the `event` object for you, regardless of browser.

Also, I'm inclined to think that you possibly can't have a `form` inside a `form`, so there shouldn't be a need to specifically select for a "form with class `edit_tag`", shouldn't there? Probably just `$(this).closest('form')` should suffice?

Comment: Or simply `$(this)`. And you are right, nested forms do not make much sense.

Comment: Good catch. Modified to put that in.

Comment: How do I have a nested form? I think I have only one form there. I tried it with `$(this)`, `$(this)[0]`, and `$(event.target)`, etc. See updated code, above. In any case, the selector is working fine -- as mentioned I tested it with a different jQuery function and it's doing its job. The form just won't submit.

Comment: If you only have one form, then `$('form').submit()` alone should do the trick, without the `.closest()` call. Although if selectors work fine, as you say, then I doubt that'll change anything.

Comment: Could it probably be something so trivial as making sure that the target of your `form` actually points to a real, valid page? "tags/3" sounds dubious, even if you're using MVC routes. Does it change anything if you actually put in an absolute path there (like `http://my.domain.com/tags/3`)?

Comment: That's an idea. I tried adding a submit button to the form and clicking it and that works as expected. So the target is OK.